# Get the specfic Rows in DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I get the spefic row in DataGridView?
Example Data

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
 asd1    asd1    asd1
 asd2    asd2    asd2
 asd3    asd3    asd3
```

I tried this code

```
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value.ToString
DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

But I'm getting this error

> index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: How do you add rows/bind the `DataGridView`

Comment: @un-lucky im using this code `DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray(0), dr.ItemArray(1), dr.ItemArray(2))`

Comment: which line shows the error

Comment: @un-lucky `DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString` that code

Comment: Firstly, it sounds like you're loading data into the grid manually from a data reader.  Don't.  Create a `DataTable` and call its `Load` method to automatically load the data into the `DataTable` and then bind that to the grid by assigning it to the `DataSource` property.

Comment: As for your issue, if those indexes into the `Rows` collection are invalid then that means that there are no rows in your grid.  You must be executing that code either before you add the rows, after you remove them or on the wrong grid.  We can't tell you more because we don't know enough about your code.

Comment: Does all the records loaded successfully into DatagridView because your code above about getting the value of the cells is correct, unless the getting the value of the cells was executed first before the records loaded into your DatagridView.